# Force step to be cached in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

Say I have line like this in a Dockerfile:

```
RUN git fetch origin my_branch
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

is there a way to force docker to use the cache for these lines? Something like:

```
FORCE-CACHE-ON
RUN git fetch origin my_branch
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CACHE-OFF
```

Comment: Docker will always use the cache if it can, unless you explicitly `docker build --no-cache`.  What would this proposed option do?

Comment: It would force the cache to be used - docker will turn off the cache if previous steps changed

Comment: I think there is no way to do that. Put your changed instructions after instructions need cached

Answer (score 0):

Docker's layer cache essentially says "if I start from image 01234567, and `RUN some command`, then I will get image 2468ace0".  If something has changed and you now have image 13579bdf instead, there's no way to short-circuit this besides running the command again.

There's a couple of approaches that can help mitigate this:

- Run heavy-weight commands that don't actually depend on the application code early in your Dockerfile.  `RUN apt-get install` before you `COPY .`.
- Minimize the amount of stuff in one image.  Don't try to put two separate applications with lengthy builds in the same image.
- Use multi-stage builds, where each stage can independently take advantage of the cache, and you'll have a relatively cheap `COPY` into the final image.
- Pre-compile some part of the sequence on the host, and `COPY` the result into the image rather than `RUN lengthy-install`.  (This was an extremely useful technique before there were multi-stage builds, and is still relevant.)